# How to infer/narrow-down a function parameter type based on the narrowed-down type of another function parameter?

Tags: typescript

In my application, there are two color formats: hex and rgb. A hex color is stored as a string, and an rgb color is stored as an object that adheres to the following interface: `{ r: number; g: number; b: number; a: number }`. My type definitions look like this:

```js
type Color<T> =
  T extends 'hex' ? string :
  T extends 'rgb' ? ColorRgb :
  never

type ColorRgb = { r: number; g: number; b: number; a: number }

// Infer color value type via color format
type T0 = Color<'hex'> // string ✅
type T1 = Color<'rgb'> // ColorRgb ✅
```

Here, `T0` and `T1` are inferred as expected.

### Problem statement

I’m having trouble writing a function for which one parameter is narrowed down based on the value of another parameter. The following piece of code is my starting point. It’s a function that takes `format` and `value` parameters. What exactly it does matters not.

What I want to accomplish is this: If I narrow down the value of the `format` parameter (e.g. an if statement checking whether `format === 'hex'`), I want TypeScript to somehow infer the type of the `value` parameter. When `format === 'hex'`, `value` should be of type `string`; when `format === 'rgb'`, `value` should be of type `ColorRgb`.

```js
function processColor (format: 'hex' | 'rgb', value: string | ColorRgb) {
  if (format === 'hex') {
    console.log(format, value) // format: 'hex' ✅, value: string | ColorRgb ❌
  } else {
    console.log(format, value) // format: 'rgb' ✅, value: string | ColorRgb ❌
  }
}
```

### Approach 1: function overloads

One approach I followed was using [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

```js
function processColor2 (format: 'hex', value: string);
function processColor2 (format: 'rgb', value: ColorRgb);
function processColor2 (format: 'hex' | 'rgb', value: string | ColorRgb) {
  if (format === 'hex') {
    console.log(format, value) // format: 'hex' ✅, value: string | ColorRgb ❌
  } else {
    console.log(format, value) // format: 'rgb' ✅, value: string | ColorRgb ❌
  }
}
```

It appears to me that function overloads are a way to specifically make *calling* a function more restrictive as this implementation doesn’t change the situation with regards to my goal at all.

### Approach 2: generic function with constraints

Another approach I looked into was using a [generic function with constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).

```js
function processColor3<T extends 'hex' | 'rgb'> (format: T, value: Color<T>) {
  if (format === 'hex') {
    console.log(format, value) // format: T extends 'hex' | 'rgb' ❌, value: Color<T> ❌
  } else {
    console.log(format, value) // format: T extends 'hex' | 'rgb' ❌, value: Color<T> ❌
  }
}
```

Here, I’m actually surprised to see that I’m *losing* type information within the function definition. Despite narrowing down the `format` parameter to be `'hex'` in the `if` branch, its type is now reported as `T extends 'hex' | 'rgb'`. I might be misunderstanding what exactly conditional types can accomplish or I might be using them incorrectly.

---

How can I tell TypeScript to infer a function parameter type based on the *narrowed-down* type of another function parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both overloads and generic conditional types are, as you noticed, really only good for guaranteeing type safety for the *caller* of the function.  Inside the *implementation* of the function, the compiler loses information necessary to maintain type safety.

For overloads this is intentional; it is the implementer's responsibility to satisfy the call signatures' contracts and the compiler doesn't really try to verify it.  There was a suggestion to change this at [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235) but this was closed as too complex.

For generic conditional types the issue is that inside the function implementation, any generic type parameters are *unspecified*.  Conditional types that depend on unspecified type parameters are mostly *deferred* and not evaluated.  The compiler therefore doesn't really see any concrete values as assignable to such types; there is an open issue asking for some way to deal with this, at least for return types, at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). Even for non-conditional types, unspecified generics tend not to be very easy to manipulate.

(update TS4.3 has improved the following situation by [narrowing values of generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#contextual-narrowing-for-generics) but it still does not narrow the generic type itself)

<strike>One major barrier is that testing a value of type `T` with a type guard (e.g., `format === 'hex'`) does not do the sort of [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) you get for specific types.  In your case, `format` is not narrowed at all.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) for more information.</strike>

A barrier to fixing this in general is that the compiler does not keep track of *correlations* between multiple expressions of union types.  In your code, you want to say that `format` and `value` are both union of types, but they are not *independent*. With each union having two members, the compiler will always assume that the pair `[format, value]` can have up to four possible types corresponding to each member from each union, as if they were independent. Even though you know that the type of `format` is correlated with the type of `value` so that only two possible types exist for `[format, value]`, the compiler just does not notice such things.  I have an issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#30851](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) wishing for some support for this, but compilers don't run on wishes.

---

So what can you do?  All you can do in the *general* case is to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the equivalent to just tell the compiler about things it can't verify.  For example, you could make an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that does nothing at runtime but tells the compiler to narrow the type of its parameter to some specified type, like this:

```
function compileTimeAssert<T>(x: any): asserts x is T {}
```

And then inside your implementation you can use it:

```
    if (format === 'hex') {
        compileTimeAssert<string>(value); // I'm telling the compiler this
        console.log(format, value.toUpperCase());
    } else {
        compileTimeAssert<ColorRgb>(value); // I'm telling the compiler this
        console.log(format, value.r);
    }
```

Such assertions are only as type safe as you make them; the responsibility for guaranteeing type safety has been shifted from the compiler to you, so be careful.

---

In the specific example you've given, I'd be inclined to change `Color` from a conditional type to an object property lookup like this:

```
interface ColorMap {
    hex: string;
    rgb: ColorRgb;
}
type Color<T extends keyof ColorMap> = ColorMap[T];
```

It's not necessary to do this, but it's easier for the compiler to reason about.  Unless there's a compelling reason why you want to be able to write `Color<Date>` and have it evaluate to `never`, I'd do it that way.

Then, I'd suggest thinking of `processColor()` as a function whose [rest parameter is a tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).  So instead of `(a: A, b: B)=>void`, it's `(...args: [A, B])=>void`. Your constraint corresponds to having the rest parameter type be a *union* of tuples. You can make the compiler calculate this type:

```
type ProcessColorParams =
    { [K in keyof ColorMap]: [format: K, value: Color<K>] }[keyof ColorMap];
// type ProcessColorParams = 
//   [format: "hex", value: string] | [format: "rgb", value: ColorRgb]
```

You can see that `ProcessColorParams` is a union where either the first element is `"hex"` and the second element is `string`, or where the first element is `"rgb"` and the second element is `ColorRgb`.  And since the first element is a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types), this union is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), where you can check the first element and the compiler will automatically narrow down the remaining elements.

So `processColor` can become tihs:

```
function processColor(...args: ProcessColorParams) {
    if (args[0] === 'hex') {
        console.log(args[0], args[1].toUpperCase());
    } else {
        console.log(args[0], args[1].r);
    }
}
```

Now the constraint is enforced from the call side *and* understood in the implementation. Yes, `args[0]` and `args[1]` are uglier than `format` and `value`, but if you break apart a discriminated union into separate variables you'll run into the problem with correlation I mentioned above.  If you want to do this, do it after you discriminate the union:

```
function processColor(...args: ProcessColorParams) {
    if (args[0] === 'hex') {
        const [format, value] = args;
        console.log(format, value.toUpperCase());
    } else {
        const [format, value] = args;
        console.log(format, value.r);
    }
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26oFk4AOyA3gLABQyVyAFhAB4BcyAzmFKAOYDcF1yUTgCNmGbFABKw3uQC+FCmACeBFGJwAeACrIGkEABMWyANYQl6GGiw58BAHzIAvNfF2A2loC6MxSrU2ksLOJALMIACuALZC0NzInOHRsVDxIsiRMXHIcElZUMjy5BQA9CXIAJIgMNDICIHIAG5wmBEoyqpNwHB1DTA4UXBgfp1aAAwh6lAaAOR09DOOZazsXMiAoOQjKFoAjJOBs4JCi8jLU1JCGwrkMBEgCGDA6CC9UQTAmBBawFEQAIIsFjQMDaewACiYORASgAlMw4IDgcZ6MhgMYdMRCtdbvdHs9kAQoOgkICpmD+lBBmBmHMGDNkAAfZAzI4zAA0TRabWYbA4IE4jNcOAuMJIfGowCs5IGQ2cThctIWorIlH41Hqbw+Xx+-0RUBBvK44OarQgMJkavVzxYWAgADpsJxpZShhyTW07WB0ABVAiqKCoBEQMEw83iqiyXSYIFi1WWjXvT7fX4AoH6jTnYTGrlmi2W3ogG2fB3oJ0UqlunN2qBhuNYuTXDooAAKRJJLCmzbgUDgUWMTnDoXcAGlUS8zBYrFM7F5mO5y0NmMPK6bRAdh-YvIV3BPLEK8IQfKVyk3kK3iRBSYEuz2+yF5zLqcgAETzZ8r7krPmcLdMh8up9nyOd9OVXfcLi8bE7geJ4XkJC8r3EAAmME7TQ7tOBYZhz3bTtu17FhlUHSVkDBDCWHcMYt3lBV5hmIi634epC1tEsnXIyivA5Didi8T0fT9aBAyBENa34SMIGjFAVXzAsi3tR0yMECiqO45T3F46sxOoIoigoHEYPxeDcMCABmVD0OU7C20vDtr3wvsGP4EilMwzi5VouknPzZi2GQf8K1AtpqJyZS83ja1WMUhcwA-e0vV9f1hODUNwsKKMYxknzrTAfyYrikLyLSpjIuLaLHzirS0t0oA)